# Paper Trading App with API compatibility

Tags: api, finance

I'm looking for a free app that will allow me to paper trade. TD Ameritrade, ETrader, and a few others have apps that allow you to do this if you open an account with them. However, I am also hoping the paper trading app will have an API for it so I can run my tradings off of them and I don't have to manually enter orders.

Does anyone know of such an app? It is most preferable that I don't have to open an account.